How to display a ER diagram with a large number of tables?
I have over 200 MySQL tables in one database. How to display them in an ER diagram elegantly?
It's not to seek help for tools, it's for some theory. Once the table number up to 100, the whole ER diagram would become very ugly and hard to read. And I have no ideal for this.
Thanks for any tips, theories or books!
